# on link click display content in new div on same page, php/mysqli

Tags: php, html

I need a little quick help from you guys

Normally this is how we redirect to a new page, by getting the required  output.

```
<a href="read.php?id=<?php echo $dn1['id']; ?>
```

I don't want to open a new page, instead I want to handle on the same page.

How to display main content in one `<div>` and on click display the detailed content on the 2nd `<div>` w.r.t `<a href=>` value.

```
<div> id | name | content </div>
```

Once any link is clicked it should display its replaced content in to 2nd div

```
<div>  Details content goes here  </div>
```

I have this scenario, but it does not give any option to place any value in href.

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('test').style.display = 'block';">
Reply</a>

                <div class="element" id="test" style="display:none;">
```

Comment: whats the reason for negative marking ,, without giving any commnets

Comment: Possibly the fact that words like <div> were invisible in your text. I've corrected that now, but next time please proofread before you hit post.

Answer (score 0):

> **You Can do this using of " iframe " tag**

*set target Attribute in " a "tag  (name of iframe)*

```
<a href="read.php?id=<?php echo $dn1['id']; ?> target="ifrm"> </a>


<div> id | name | content </div>

once any link is clicked it should display its replated content in to 2nd div

<div> <iframe name="ifrm"></iframe> Details content goes here  </div>
```

Comment: cant it just go by setting an id for div, and then targetting it ???
<div id="test" > , anu possiblities for this scenario